# pad,pad-front functions in XML

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Maybe is a dummy question but i can't find specific research for this functions in XML  where there's detailed explanation for them,i see lot of developers in most of the programing languages use this functions especially in data integrations but still i can't find specific explanation..i think there's something with  the strings and make them shorter..but in that case we use substring(),substring-after() and substring-before()..

What is the crucial difference between them can anyone tell me?

Regards.

Comment: Please have a look at https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#section-String-Functions

Comment: Are you asking where the documentation is for the "pad" function in XSLT? The answer is that their isn't any, as there isn't a built-in pad function. However, if you are looking to do padding, you can use existing string functions to do it. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31805587/pad-value-with-fix-length-xslt for example.